# How to stop the process of \int_step_inline in LaTeX3?

Tags: expl3, latex3

Here is a MWE:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 5 }
  {
    #1
    \int_compare:nNnT {#1} > {3}
      {
        % I want to stop for this case
      }
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\end{document}
```

I want to stop the process of `\int_step_inline` or some similar functions on some particular condition. I know there is `break` of `continue` in `Python`. Is there any similar functions in `LaTeX3` that do the same things?

Comment: I guess I'm wondering why you'd want to do this - the `step` function is for the case where you know you want to use every value in a range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although it's not currently documented, one can use the generic `\prg_break:` to terminate these constructs early:

```latex
\ExplSyntaxOn
\int_step_inline:nn { 100 }
  {
    \int_compare:nNnT {#1} > { 50 }
      { \prg_break: }
    \message { #1 }
  }
\stop
```

Comment: I check it in `interface3` and I saw `\prg_break` is used with `\prg_break_point:`, but what about the case here?

Comment: @xdyy `\prg_break_point:` provides a generic mechanism to implement mappings and similar with a 'way out' using `\prg_break:`. It's therefore used in the implementation of `\int_step_inline:nn` and similar functions. Like I said, that's not documented - I guess I will need to raise with the team.

Comment: I wonder what's the functions of `\message` and `\stop` here?

Comment: @xdyy They are for the demo: `\message` gets TeX to write to the terminal and log, so we don't have to worry about typesetting anything to see the result. `\stop` is a LaTeX command that just stops the run - useful in demos or debugging.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed answers!